# SQL Server linked server query issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, distributed-databases, distributed-queries

I am using SQL Server 2016 and recently one of the stored procedures I have been using is throwing error. I use a select statement with joins on many tables to the remote server using a linked server

**SQL**

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT a.col1,
       b.col1
  FROM [LinkedServer].[Database].[Schema].[TableA] AS a
  JOIN [LinkedServer].[Database].[Schema].[TableB] AS b
    ON a.col2 = b.col2

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

**Error**

```
New request is not allowed to start because it should come with valid transaction descriptor
```

When I change the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` to `BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION` I am running into a different error `OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server was unable to begin a distributed transaction`.

The remote server too is SQL Server 2016.

Not sure on how to resolve the errors.

Comment: Hi @AaronBertrand, To illustrate the example I have one `SELECT` but I have a few `SELECT` `UPDATE` & `DELETE` clubbed into one transaction.

Comment: Could this issue arise due to database fragmentation? There are several other stored procedures which access this remote database but only one stored procedure is running into this issue.